# How do you cancel an Upstart script's stop in the pre-stop stanza?

Tags: bash, shell, upstart

Upstart documentation states (referring to the `pre-stop` stanza):

> You can also use this stanza to cancel the stop, in a similar fashion to the way one can cancel the start in the pre-start.

[[Source]](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-stop)

The example of cancelling the start in the `pre-start` stanza is:

```
pre-start script

  # stop job from continuing if no config file found for daemon
  [ ! -f /etc/default/myapp ] && { stop; exit 0; }

  # source the config file
  . /etc/default/myapp

  # stop job from continuing if admin has not enabled service in
  # config file.
  [ -z "$ENABLED" ] && { stop; exit 0; }

end script
```

[[Source]](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start)

This makes sense, because it will exit the script. However, doing an `exit` in the `pre-stop` stanza will also exit the script, and not cancel the stop. Is that accurate? How can you use the `pre-stop` stanza to actually cancel the `stop`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `start` keyword instead of the `stop`. This will put the job back in the start/running state from the start/pre-stop state.

```
pre-stop script
    start
end script
```